# Speed of MicroSDXC Card for Nintendo Switch

Tags: nintendo-switch, performance

I want to extend the storage available on my Switch (OLED) with a MicroSDXC card.

The [officially licensed ones](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/memory-cards/sandisk-nintendo-switch-microsd#SDSQXAO-512G-ANCZN) have the following specs:

> Sequential Read Performance Up to 100MB/s
>
> Sequential Write Performance Up to 90MB/s

Is there a noticable benefit of having a card faster than that or is the difference in loading time (of games installed on the card) negligible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nintendo Switch only supports UHS-1 cards, which have a maximum possible speed of 104MB/s, compared to the 312MB/s speed limit of the more modern UHS-2 standard.

However, [Eurogamer's testing](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-the-best-micro-sd-cards-for-nintendo-switch-7000) revealed only a tiny differential between the slowest and fastest UHS-1 Micro SD cards on the Switch, so their recommendations are tailored towards capacity and value rather than speed.